# Trying to make a search bar with a MINI PHP MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am trying to make a search bar for my application.

I am using the following Mini Framework: https://github.com/panique/mini

What I want to do is have an input field where you type an username, and then a table is displayed underneath with all the information from the Database.

Environment:

- PHP 7.4
- Apache
- CentOS 8
- SQL Server 2019

My problem is, I don't know how to pass the input value to the controller and then to the model.

Let me show you what I have tried:

**Account Model:**

```
public function getUser($name)
{
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.user_table WHERE Name = :name ORDER BY UserID DESC";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':name' => $name));

    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

**Account Controller:**

```
/**
 * ACTION: getUser
 */
public function getUser()
{       
    if(isset($_POST['search_user'])) {
        $checkUser = $this->model->getUser($_POST['username']);
    }
}
```

**My View:**

```
<form action="<?php echo URL; ?>account/getUser" method="POST" class="mb20">
        <div class="row">                  
            <div class="input-wrap col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Type username" name="username" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>                                      
        </div></br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Search" name="search_user" />
    </form>
```

I am not sure how to `echo` the result in the view. Maybe someone here could guide me in the correct direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Account Controller:**

```
/**
 * ACTION: getUser
 */
public function search()
{       
    if(isset($_POST['search_user'])) {
        $checkUser = $this->model->getUser($_POST['username']);
    }
    require APP . 'view/search/index.php'; // your search view path

}
```

**Search View:**

```
<form action="<?php echo URL; ?>search" method="POST" class="mb20">
  <div class="row">                  
      <div class="input-wrap col-sm-12">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Type username" name="username" autocomplete="off" />
      </div>                                      
  </div></br> 
  <input type="submit" value="Search" name="search_user" />
</form> 

<?php

if (isset($checkUser)) {
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach ($checkUser as $key => $value) {
    echo '<li>';
    echo $value->name;
    echo '</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

In this way, if there's the `$_POST['search_user']`, the function `search` will perform the search and put the result on the `$checkUser` variable. The variable will be still present on the View because you're requiring it after the `$checkUser` declaration. Then, the View checks if the variable is present and displays the results.

**IMPORTANT**

The line `echo $value->name;` is a dangerous behavior, because it can allow [XSS](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/), so, before rendering anything from the database, remember to escape it properly. Some ways to do it:

[How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strip-tags.php